# Wordpress + PHP: Getting Option Value into Variable

Tags: php, wordpress, variables

I am sure this must be easy for you people but I am troubling to get my theme option value into one of the variable.

In below code I have to use " " for value and that value I am allowing user to insert from wordpress theme option panel. I don't know how to set this so I can get theme option value in this variable.

```
$rate_size="echo get_option('mp_star_size')",
```

I have tried with

```
$rate_size="'.echo get_option('mp_star_size').'",
```

but its giving me syntax error so don't know what syntax I should use.

Alright here is more details what I am trying to get

Below code:

```
    wp_gdsr_render_article(

            $stars_set="",
            $stars_size=0,
            $stars_set_ie6="",
            $echo=true

        );
```

I want allow my theme user to select option from theme option panel in wordpress theme. So I want to set with echo get_option() something like that so I can get value from option panel to each parameter of this code.

example:

```
    wp_gdsr_render_article(

            $stars_set="here is my theme option",
            $stars_size=here is my theme option,
            $stars_set_ie6="here is my theme option",
            $echo=here is my theme option

        );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$rate_size = get_option('mp_star_size');
```

`echo` is only for displaying content on the page.

Comment: what about "" quote? as it is required wrap the value...its not getting output to the page

Comment: No, it isn't. The quotes delimit strings and `get_option()` returns a string, so you're good. Post the exact code you've used and the error you get.

Comment: Error was my mistake.
This is my theme option `array( "name" => "Star Size",
 "desc" => "Select size for star ratings.",
 "id" => $shortname."_star_size",
 "type" => "select",
 "options" => array("12" => "12", "16" => "16", "20" => "20", "24" => "24", "30" => "30", "46" => "46"),
 "std" => "12"),` prefix is mp and I am trying to connect with my posted code

Comment: This is the function what I am working on `function article_ratings($class) { 
  
  echo '<div class="'.$class.'">';
  
  wp_gdsr_render_article(
  
    $template_id=0,
    $read_only=false,
    $stars_set="",
    $stars_size=0,
    $stars_set_ie6="",
    $echo=true
    
   );
   
  wp_gdsr_render_article_thumbs(
  
    $template_id=0,
    $read_only=false,
    $stars_set="",
    $stars_size=0,
    $stars_set_ie6="",
    $echo=true
    
   );
   
  echo '</div>';

 }`

Comment: Cool its working in many cases let me connect with all and get back to you again.. :)

Comment: I have tried without "" for $star_set but its not getting the value

Comment: Alright its done.. there was an issue with plugin fields name. Solved and thanks a lot..